# Facebook Feed Dialog API how to include a redirect_uri containing a #?

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, deep-linking, fragment-identifier

How can I specify a `redirect_uri` containing a `#`?

[Facebook Feed Dialog API parameters reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#params)

> `redirect_uri` - The URL to redirect to after a person clicks a button
>   on the dialog. Required when using URL redirection.

This works as expected when the `redirect_uri` in question is a regular URL, however, when it contains a `#` it stops working.

When `redirect_uri` is `http://website.com/foo`, it redirects to:

`https://website.com/foo?post_id=100006935442054_1384656491776519#_=_`

Not sure what the trailing `#_=_` is for, but it does not cause any issues here.

When `redirect_uri` is `http://website.com/#foo`, it redirects to:

`https://website.com/?post_id=100006935442054_1384656491776629#_=_`

Thus it appear that either the parameters after the `#` are ignored, or overridden with `#_=_`

Given that I am working with a single page application, whose routes are driven by the hash fragment, this breaks my ability to deep link within my application.

Any help/ suggestions on how to work around this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your application you can handle query strings as if it was a hash tag, or simply do a redirect.

For example, if your route is `http://website.com/#foo`, make `http://website.com/?hash=foo` do the same thing or redirect `?hash=foo` to `#foo`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a problem like this right now. The URL to go in redirect_uri and link:

```
.../xfile.jsp?item=/contests/bhg_homeimprovement/bhg_splashsweeps_win2500_homeimprovement&temp=yes&hid=#HashID#&esrc=nwbhgsweeps072514a
```

The FB dialog gets an error as is. Encoding the full URL fixes that and does output hashes around "HashID", but the equal sign before it is removed. Adding a 2nd equal sign there will output 2 equal signs, but having just one will output none.

This isn't a complete solution but it does look like hash marks are possible.